# Store a custom site for every user ( dynamic content ) Svelte

Tags: url-routing, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, dynamic-content

I'm building an e-commerce marketplace with Firebase and Svelte where every user can create their store. Not every store will look the same. The users will structure their site using pre-made components and behind the scenes, it might look something like this:

```
<Header logo="" name"".../>
<FAQ questions=.../>
<ProductList .../>
<ContactForm .../>
<Footer .../>
```

or like:

```
<Header logo="" name"".../>
<Video link="".../>
<ProductList .../>
<MailingList .../>
<Footer .../>
```

And yes, I know about `<svelte:component this={...}/>` for dynamic components.

But how should I store the sites? Should I just keep the full ".svelte" file in a field of the store's document in the database, then on the client side just create every component with the technique I talked about above? This seems pretty inefficient and heavy in the long run. What's the standard way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course when I'm saying " keep the full ".svelte" file in a field of the store's document in the database"

I mean to store the file's content, not the file itself ( I don't know how you would do that but it's always better to make things clear )

Comment: I doubt that there is a "standard way of doing it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably store the structure as JSON to decouple it from the implementation, e.g.

```json
[
  { type: "header", name: "Maru Store" },
  { type: "video", link: "..." },
  { type: "product-list" },
  { type: "mailing-list" },
  { type: "footer" }
]
```

(Quite possibly with additional containers for layout purposes, e.g. vertical/horizontal/grid.)

Then a generic component can resolve this.

```html
{#if descriptor.type == 'header'}
  <Header name={descriptor.name} />
{:else if ...}
  ...
{/if}
```

If e.g. a layout container is found, `{#each}` can be used with `<svelte:self>` for recursion.

This should not be that impactful for a few components. The DB query result can also be cached to prevent round trips.

Comment: It's way too hard to read without indent so: https://pastebin.com/vda5h17a

Comment: That might work. I was a bit weary of that approach specifically because some components might need special handling, but you could probably start with that and create special cases as needed.

Comment: what do you mean by special handling?

Comment: E.g. adding events or passing in slot content.

Comment: Aghh you're right, I'll see if I can get other suggestions from other people but if I don't, I'll accept this answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Building further on @H.B. answer, if you store the structures like this:

```
[
  { type: "header", name: "Maru Store" },
  { type: "video", link: "..." },
  { type: "product-list" },
  { type: "mailing-list" },
  { type: "footer" }
]
```

You can use a 'mapping' Object to link types and components:

```html
<script>
  // other imports omitted for brevity
  import Header from './Header.svelte';
 
  // the blocks the user wants to have
  export const blocks = [];

  // the map
  const map = {
    'header': Header,
    'video': Video,
    'product-list': ProductList
  }

</script>

{#each blocks as block}
  <svelte:component this={block.type} {...block} />
{/each}
```

This has the benefit that all you have to do when adding new types is import them and change the map without going around with imports and as long as those different types of components are not overly large the extra overhead of bundling them all is negligible.

If you have hundreds of types of components you could try your hand at dynamically loading the components instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate it! If you look under the replies of his answer I sent a link to some code really similar to yours. This confirms what I thought.